# The meaning of "c'est fou ce que" vs "c'est fou que"

Tags: sens

> Quand on est étiqueté mouton noir, **c'est fou ce qu**'on a le dos large.

The "c'est fou ce que" part in the sentence above has me puzzled. How does this construction differ in meaning from saying "c'est fou que" as below?

> Quand on est étiqueté mouton noir, **c'est fou qu**'on a le dos large.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Quand on est étiqueté mouton noir, **c'est fou ce qu**'on a le dos large.

The "C'est fou ce qu'on" can be translated to: "It's **crazy how** we've...."

> Quand on est étiqueté mouton noir, **c'est fou qu**'on a le dos large.

Is not really a valid construct.  It could be translated as "it's **crazy that** we've...".

Comment: Why does the "ce que" translate into "how" in this case, considering that "ce que" usually means "what"? Thanks.

Comment: That's called polysemy.

Comment: Like for many idioms, it's best not to dwell too much on the "why".

Comment: @DaWaaaaghBabal           Hi. So the phrase "c'est fou ce que" as a whole is like an idiom that shouldn't be considered separately? If so, does this example sentence mean something like "It's crazy how we get blamed unfairly"?

Comment: The idiom _avoir le dos large_ means _être capable d'encaisser_, (being able to endure many difficulties).  It _could_ be translated to "be blamed unfairly", like in this case, but it depends on the context.

Comment: Like many idioms, you somehow need to grok it to really appreciate it.

Comment: @pourraitPeut-être Translate them litterally : "C'est fou que.." -> "It's mad that(conj.)..." vs. "C'est fou ce que..." -> "It's mad, that(pron.) that(conj.)..."